# Check if Pandas column contains value from another column

Tags: python, pandas

if `df['col']='a','b','c'` and `df2['col']='a123','b456','d789'` how do I create `df2['is_contained']='a','b','no_match'` where if values from `df['col']` are found within values from `df2['col']` the `df['col']` value is returned and if no match is found, 'no_match' is returned? Also I don't expect there to be multiple matches, but in the unlikely case there are, I'd want to return a string like 'Multiple Matches'.

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple matches"?  Do you mean the two `'a'`s in `'a123a'`, or do you mean in different rows of df2['col'], e.g. `['a123','b456','a789']`?

Comment: The latter case where different rows are matched

Answer (score 8):

With this toy data set, we want to add a new column to `df2` which will contain `no_match` for the first three rows, and the last row will contain the value `'d'` due to the fact that that row's `col` value (the letter `'a'`) appears in df1.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['a123','b456','d789', 'a']})
```

In other words, values from `df1` should be used to populate this new column in `df2` only when a row's `df2['col']` value appears somewhere in `df1['col']`.

```
In [2]: df1
Out[2]:
  col
0   a
1   b
2   c
3   d

In [3]: df2
Out[3]:
    col
0  a123
1  b456
2  d789
3     a
```

If this is the right way to understand your question, then you can do this with pandas `isin`:

```
In [4]: df2.col.isin(df1.col)
Out[4]:
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
Name: col, dtype: bool
```

This evaluates to `True` only when a value in `df2.col` is also in `df1.col`.

Then you can use `np.where` which is more or less the same as `ifelse` in R if you are familiar with R at all.

```
In [5]:     np.where(df2.col.isin(df1.col), df1.col, 'NO_MATCH')
Out[5]:
0    NO_MATCH
1    NO_MATCH
2    NO_MATCH
3           d
Name: col, dtype: object
```

For rows where a `df2.col` value appears in `df1.col`, the value from `df1.col` will be returned for the given row index. In cases where the `df2.col` value is not a member of `df1.col`, the default `'NO_MATCH'` value will be used.

Comment: I actually want it to match on a partial match. So in your example every value would have a match. I don't think isin handles partial matching.

Comment: your output does not solve the question. he wanted to have a row wise comparison of two columns.

Answer (score 3):

You must first guarantee that the indexes match. To simplify, I'll show as if the columns where in the same dataframe. The trick is to use the apply method in the **columns axis**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                   'col2': ['a123','b456','d789', 'a']})
df['contained'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.col1 in x.col2, axis=1)
df
  col1  col2  contained
0    a  a123       True
1    b  b456       True
2    c  d789      False
3    d     a      False
```

Answer (score 1):

In 0.13, you can use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.extract.html):

```
In [11]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['a', 'b', 'c']})

In [12]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['d23','b456','a789']})

In [13]: df2.col.str.extract('(%s)' % '|'.join(df1.col))
Out[13]: 
0    NaN
1      b
2      a
Name: col, dtype: object
```